# Updating interval on main thread for a timer

Tags: java, android, andengine

Okay i need to know if there is a more efficient way to go about this.

I am using AndEngine to place sprites on a Scene in a method.

Now throughout the game i update the intervals that the Sprites should be spawned.

I update the intervals throughout my code.

For example i have a Timer that adds sprites at a interval, and i can change the interval

```
private void speed(int f, int g, int h){

    this.nextSprite1Time = f;
    this.nextSprite2Time = g;
    this.nextSprite3Time = h;
    Log.d("Time Changed", String.valueOf(this.nextSprite1Time+ "," + this.nextSprite2Time + ","+ this.nextSprite3Time));

     }
```

When this method is ran there is a 3 second lag that takes place, and it freezes.

How can avoid this with safe threading, or anything?

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Here is my time handler.

```
mScene.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(0.02f, true, new ITimerCallback() {
                   @Override
                   public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                          addSpriteTime1 += 2; // because timer update = 0.02 seconds
                           if (addSpriteTime1 >= nextSprite1Time) {
                                  addFace();
                                  addSpriteTime1 -= nextSprite1Time;

                           }

                           addSpriteTime2 += 2;
                           if (addSpriteTime2 >= nextSprite2Time) {
                                 addFace2();
                                   addSpriteTime2 -= nextSprite2Time;
                           }

                           addSpriteTime3 += 2;
                           if (addSpriteTime3 >= nextSprite3Time) {
                                   addFace3();
                                   addSpriteTime3 -= nextSprite3Time;
                           }
                   }
           }));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [TimerHandler in andengine spawing sprites at a interval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868038/timerhandler-in-andengine-spawing-sprites-at-a-interval)

Comment: @TedHopp How is this a duplicate? Talking about two completely different things?

Comment: How is it different things? In both questions, you are asking about why your program stops after you update these three same variables. Also, you provide no info here from which anyone could help you. The above function obviously doesn't, in itself, freeze. Something else is going on in your program and you provide no context. How are these variables used? What does it mean that "it freezes"--is there an error message? There's a 3 second lag until...what? Provide some relevant details, please, and then perhaps you'll get some help.

Comment: What values are you passing to `speed`? Does your program actually freeze? or does it stop calling `onTimePassed`? or does it stop adding faces? If the last, perhaps it would help to log some values inside `onTimePassed` to see what's happening.

Comment: Well it doesnt stop running persay, what happens is it lags or freezes for about 2 seconds, i was wondering was their a better way to update the times, because when i use the speed method it freezes for a good 2 seconds, and really throughs the sequence of the game off.

Comment: It only does this on cellular devices on tablets it runs fine because of the cpu speed

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6748/discussion-between-ted-hopp-and-coder-for-life22)